# Analysing runtime

Tags: recursion, runtime, probability

I came across a question to implement an unbiased random function which outputs 0 or 1 using a biased output function which outputs 0 or 1 with probability P for outputting 1. And to predict how the runtime varies in accordance with P

I implemented it as follows

```
Random() {
     i = BRand();
     j = BRand();

    if(i!=j)
          Return i;
    else
           Random();
    }
```

But I'm unable to figure out how the runtime would vary in terms of P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say `BRand` has a 70% chance (`P = 0.7`) to produce a one (1), and thus a 30% chance (`1 - P`) to produce a zero (0) -

```
i = 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
j = 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

We only return a result when `i != j`, so that rules out any combination where `(i, j)` both produce a zero, `(0, 0)`, or both produce a one, `(1, 1)`. The effect of running `Random()` once is thus -

- 30% * 30% = **9%** probability of `(0, 0)`, recur
- 70% * 70% = **49%** probability of `(1, 1)`, recur
- 30% * 70% = **21%** probability of `(0, 1)`, return `0`
- 70% * 30% = **21%** probability of `(1, 0)`, return `1`

Where `P = .7`, 58% (49% + 9%) of the time we will recur. In the other 42%, there is an equal probability to return either zero or one. At the low cost of recursion, indeed this clever algorithm will make an unbiased random number generator out of a biased generator.

---

Changing the probability to `P = 0.1` we see a different result:

```
i = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The effect of running `Random()` is

- 90% * 90% = **81%** probability of `(0, 0)`, recur
- 10% * 10% = **1%** probability of `(1, 1)`, recur
- 90% * 10% = **9%** probability of `(0, 1)`, return `0`
- 10% * 90% = **9%** probability of `(1, 0)`, return `1`

Where `P = 0.1`, 82% of the time we will recur. In the other 18%, there is an equal probability to return zero or one.

---

Exercise 1: Show why `P = 0.9` has the same outcome has `P = 0.1`. What relationship do you see here?

Exercise 2: What is the probability we will recur when `P = 0.001`? What about `P = 0.999`?

Exercise 3: What is special about `P = 0.5`?

After you have completed the exercises, reveal the text below -

> When `P = 0.5` we see the lowest runtime for `Random()`, with only 50% chance to recur. This makes sense because `P = 0.5` is already unbiased! Ie, the effect of running `BRand` already has equal chance to produce a zero or one. As `P` deviates from `0.5` we notice it there is a higher probability that `Random()` will recur, thus `Random()` requires a longer runtime to make an unbiased generator.

Exercise 4: Write a formula that calculates probability of recursion based on `P`

> *F(p) = p<sup>2</sup> + (1 - p)<sup>2</sup>*   —   where 0 <= *p* <= 1

Comment: I knew intuitively that as P got farther from 0.5 runtime would increase, what I was trying to obtain is a runtime analysis in a mathematical form . Like using the master formula or sthg